# How can I upload an audio response from [elevenlabs.com](https://elevenlabs.com) API to Firebase storage using Firebase functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I am trying to create a website that generate the audio from text using the [elevenlabs.com](https://elevenlabs.com) api.

And I need to upload that audio respose from `elevenlabs api` to the firebase storage through firebase functions.

I have done this.

```js
import axios from "axios";
import {FieldValue} from "firebase-admin/firestore";
import {firestore, logger} from "firebase-functions/v1";
import {db, storage} from "./lib";

export const generateClip = firestore
  .document("clips/{clipId}")
  .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
    const clipData = snapshot.data();
    if (!clipData) {
      logger.error("No data found");
      return;
    }
    const clipId = context.params.clipId;

    try {
      const res = await axios.post(
        `https://api.elevenlabs.io/v1/text-to-speech/${clipData.model}/stream`,
        {
          "text": clipData.text,
          "model_id": "eleven_monolingual_v1",
          "voice_settings": {
            "stability": 0.5,
            "similarity_boost": 0.5,
          },
        },
        {
          headers: {
            "xi-api-key": process.env.VOICE_KEY,
            "Accept": "audio/mpeg",
          },
        }
      );

      const path = `clips/${clipId}.mp3`;
      const file = storage.bucket(process.env.FIREBASE_BUCKET).file(path);
      await file.save(res.data);

      const tokensCount = (clipData.text as string).length;

      await db.doc(`clips/${clipId}`).update({
        status: "COMPLETED",
        tokens: tokensCount,
        file_path: path,
      });

      await db.doc(`users/${clipData.uid}`).update({
        tokens: FieldValue.increment(-tokensCount),
      });

      logger.info("Clip generated", {
        clipId,
        tokensCount,
        path,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      logger.error("Error generate clip", error);
      await db.doc(`clips/${clipId}`).update({
        status: "FAILED",
      });
    }
  });
```

But this is only creating the empty file in the firebase storage.

Answer (score 0):

I have [written a blog post](https://fleker.medium.com/uploading-a-photo-to-google-cloud-storage-through-firebase-callable-functions-1a545aea43ac) on this topic. The answer is to use Google Cloud Storage and those APIs to write to a bucket (and Firebase Storage is a wrapper on top of GCS).

Here's how to save the data with a base64 string of the content. In my case I was uploading an image, but this should work for any databuffer:

```
import { Bucket } from '@google-cloud/storage';
const stream = require('stream');

export const writeFile = async (bucket: Bucket, filename: string, content: string) => {
  const blob = bucket.file(`${filename}`)

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const bufferStream = new stream.PassThrough();

    bufferStream.pipe(blob.createWriteStream({
      metadata: {
        contentType: 'image/png'
      }
    }))

    bufferStream.on('error', (err: Error) => {
      reject(err)
    })

    bufferStream.on('finish', () => {
      resolve()
    })

    bufferStream.end(Buffer.from(content, 'base64'));
  })
}
```

And this can be wrapped into a Firebase Cloud Function:

```
export const checkin = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  // Do other stuff here
  // ...
  // ...

  if (fileData !== null && fileData !== '') {
    const bucket = admin.storage().bucket(`${sak.project_id}.appspot.com`) // Default bucket
    const filename = `checkins/${Math.random()}${Math.random()}.png`
    await writeFile(bucket, filename, fileData)
    console.debug(`Wrote file as ${filename}`)
    checkin.photoUrl = filename
  }
  
  const checkinRef = await db.collection('checkins').add(checkin)
  const checkinId = checkinRef.id

  if (checkin.photoUrl !== undefined) {
    await db.collection('users').doc(uid).collection('feeds').doc('photos').update({
      photos: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion({
        checkin: checkinId,
        photoUrl: checkin.photoUrl
      })
    })
  }
  
  // Do other stuff here
  // ...
  // ...
  return {
    checkinId,
    photoUrl: `https://storage.googleapis.com/${sak.project_id}.appspot.com/${checkin.photoUrl}`
  }
})
```

Comment: I have already applied this method and this is still not working.

Comment: Which part isn't working? It seems like you're pulling `storage` from another library rather than using the direct `google-cloud-storage` api.